# python's multiprocessing throws struct.error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Im running the following multiprocessing code:

```
manager = mp.Manager()
returns = manager.dict()
state = manager.dict()
pool = manager.Pool(processes=workers)
results = pool.starmap_async(extract_traces, [(
        v,
        path,
        masks[v],
        state,
        returns,
        max_frames,
        False
    ) for v in videos
])
```

It works perfectly until I increase the size of `masks` which are numpy arrays.
Then the starmap_async method throws the following error:

```
.../signal_extraction.py", line 197, in parallel_extract_traces_from_videos                                                                    
) for v in videos                                                                                                                                                                                       
File "<string>", line 2, in starmap_async                                                                                                                                                                 
File "/home/eule/anaconda3/envs/detector/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 
795, in _callmethod
conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
File "/home/eule/anaconda3/envs/detector/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 
206, in send
self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
File "/home/eule/anaconda3/envs/detector/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 
393, in _send_bytes
header = struct.pack("!i", n)
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

I understand that it has got to do with something not being in the range of 32bit but I was not able to find a solution to this anywhere.

Also when I run the `extract_traces` method from a simple for loop it works fine even with the large `masks` arrays. 
Is there some kind of a limitation for multiprocessing processes that I am exceeding?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hey did you find a way to fix it ?